# Mapping the enter key to a button in HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, enter

I have a small form in which you have to submit a score, which is a number, then i have a script which processes the number.

The form is like so:

```html
<form  name ="input2" style="margin-left: 30%; margin-right: 30%; margin-bottom:5%">
  Score:
  <input type="text" id="score" name="score" maxlength="3" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13) changePlayer();" patern="\d"><br>
  <input id = "submit" type="button" value="Submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="changePlayer(); return false"/>
  <input type="button" name="Cancel" class="btn btn-primary" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
```

I enter the number in a text box, and then when i click the submit button, the function processes the number. The thing is, i want the same thing to happen when i press enter, but instead, the page refreshes, and the whole thing starts over, i lose the data.

How can i sort of map the enter key to the button, or the function, without it refreshing the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `<input id = "submit" type="button"` to `<input id = "submit" type="submit"`. You don't need the check.

```js
function changePlayer(score) {
  alert(input2.score.value);
}
```

```html
<form name="input2" style="margin-left: 30%; margin-right: 30%; margin-bottom:5%" onsubmit="changePlayer();return false;">
  Score:
  <input type="text" id="score" name="score" maxlength="3" patern="\d"><br>
  <input id = "submit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="changePlayer(); return false"/>
  <input type="button" name="Cancel" class="btn btn-primary" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
```